# How do I search through code of lost commits?

Tags: git

I am not asking how to recover a known commit.  I am asking how to search through the content of files in the commits that appear when running commands like

```
git fsck --unreachable
git fsck --lost-found
```

I know the name of the file where the code was lost, and I can be pretty sure it was in the last week or 2.  I even have a pretty good idea where it is in the the file, but I have no idea which commit to start in.  How can I do this without going crazy?

So far the farthest I've gotten is this, but it would be helpful if it could filter out the irrelevant files and commits, and show changed code:

```
git log --graph --all --numstat --oneline --decorate --full-history --date-order --color $((git fsck --unreachable | awk '{ print $3 }'; git fsck --lost-found | awk '{ print $3 }') | grep -v 'Checking')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can feed multiple commits to `git grep`, so feed the unreachable ones:

```
mycommits=$(git fsck --unreachable | awk '$2=="commit" {print $3}')
git grep pattern $mycommits -- path/to/file
```

edit: to cut the commits down to just the last week or two,

```
printf %s\\n $mycommits | git rev-list --stdin --no-walk --since=last.week
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the `git fsck --lost-found` variant, to make it create "links" to the dangling commits (see [the `git fsck` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) for details).  This is just to make the list of commit hash IDs easier to find, and protect them from being collected (I *think* it protects them) in case Git fires up a `gc --auto`.

You now have a `.git/fsck/lost-found/commit` directory with a lot of hash IDs in it.  These are *only* commit hash IDs, so there is no further filtering required.

Then, for each "dangling commit", you can do a `git grep` or `git log` using the raw hash ID.  This won't necessarily keep your sanity, but at least you have the hash IDs in *files*, rather than in the shell's `$(...)` output.  I find this makes them a lot easier to deal with.